# Compare hash encoded passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am storing my `password` in database table column with `string` datatype. Before storing it to database I am making it `Hash encoded` using c# method below :

```
public static string Md5Encrypted(string password)
        {
            byte[] pass = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            string strPassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(pass));
            return strPassword;
        }
```

Now I want to `compare` it while inserting new password.

For that I am fetching record of specific user from database and getting his existing encoded password in string. If I use the same password then also it is not matching. For example if I pass `adgjl135` as a password it is encoded as `Pb�ZsÈU��}��` but from database what I get is `Pb?ZsÈU??}??` but obvious they will not match. Then how do I compare them? Any idea??

Comment: You're storing the passwords wrong. Either use a byte array data type in the database, or encode the hash as hexadecimal digits / base64 before storing it. (Why would you assume the MD5 of something is a valid UTF-8 string?)

Comment: Also, it's not very secure to store passwords in the database unsalted. Better than unhashed but in the case your database gets stolen people with passwords available in rainbow tables will be exposed to having their accounts compromised.

Comment: @AndreLoker Its differnt.. I want to compare passwords now as I dont have any method to decode it.

Comment: @Dev Everything you need to know has been said in that other thread. I already told you there that and how your code is broken and how you can fix it. I also posted a link that's telling you exactly how to handle hashed passwords correctly. Please take the time to read it.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, this question is now: how do I rescue the best I can of what's happened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(md5.ComputeHash(pass))
```

The result of computing a hash is *not* UTF-8-encoded text. It's binary data. When you attempt to interpret it as if it were a UTF-8-encoded string, you lose data - hence the problem.

So either store it just as binary data, or convert it to either hex or base64, both of which can be used to represent arbitrary binary data without loss.

(As an important aside, you should *not* just use MD5 to hash passwords - especially not without a salt. But that's a separate discussion, one you should *definitely* pay attention to, and one where I'm not competent to speak authoritatively.)

Comment: Just beat me to it! :P

Comment: OK. Now any method by which I can compare them? I cannot change this method as we have already exists many users..

Comment: @Dev: You *must* change. You've already lost data. Working around that will leave you even more vulnerable than if you were just using MD5 properly. Fundamentally your code is broken - and the longer it's been broken, the more painful it will be to fix. You may well end up needing to reset everyone's password. You should take this as an opportunity to fix the algorithm you use as well as the storage...

Comment: @Dev I'm sorry, but that is a big problem for you. Storing it in UTF-8 format has most likely resulted in loss of data and that's not recoverable.

Comment: We had that topic in another thread. Please modify your code and use a Base64"String".

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably noticed, the `�`, which is commonly used to express "invalid character" in UTF-8, gets replaced with an ordinary '?' in your database. You can, therefore, still compare what's left of the passwords if you regard these two characters as equal.